# Python: Each chunk of data consists of a variable amount of lines, how to determine the number of chunks total?

Tags: python, database, for-loop, multiple-entries

I have a very large file of data and each entry looks something like this:

```
    5 (this can be any number, call this line n)
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
n lines, in this case 5, i.e. lines 4 - 8
Line 9
n lines, in this case again 5, i.e. lines 10-14
Line 15
```

Essentially, each entry starts with one line, followed by 3 lines + n lines + 1 line + n lines + 1 line.

This number n, is an integer (but can vary depending on the entry). Is there a way to figure out how many data entries I have in this file?

I have some code in place for if I know how many entries there are, then I can loop over each entry... but is there a way to figure out the number of entries in the first place?

Thanks!

edit: Here are two examples of a sample entry -

```
    5
10.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 10.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 10.0
A       -0.005364798      -0.022912843       0.017346957
B        0.527031905       0.603310150       0.560736787
B       -0.629466850      -0.628385741       0.628048126
B       -0.649090857       0.603667874      -0.726135880
B        0.683741908      -0.584386774      -0.700569743
    -17.862057
  -2.022841336      -1.477407454      -5.606136767
   2.521789668       2.889251770       2.572440406
  -0.401914888      -0.722582908       0.244151982
   0.806040926      -0.990697574       1.474733506
  -0.903074369       0.301436166       1.314862295
      0.016462

     7
 10.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 10.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 10.0
 A       -0.591644968      -0.645755982      -0.014245979
 B        1.198655655      -0.588872080      -0.025169784
 B       -1.460774580      -1.255848596       0.025804796
 B        0.321839745       2.199107994       0.050450166
 C        0.617684720      -1.389588077      -0.075897238
 C        0.493712792       1.349385956      -0.004249822
 D       -0.808145644       0.577304796       0.014326943
    -26.435922
   1.649465696      -2.945456091      -0.152209323
   0.531241391      -1.113956273      -0.135548573
  -0.529287352      -0.556746737      -0.061346528
  -2.152476371       6.326868481       0.441458459
  -1.633473432       3.325310912       0.291306019
   0.726490986      -8.268565793      -0.512575180
   1.408090505       3.232545501       0.128915126
      0.155658
```

The first number, an integer (5 or 7 in these examples), determines the number of lines that follows this entry:

```
 10.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 10.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 10.0
```

As well as the number of lines that follow the line after, which in the first case is:
    -17.862057

Each entry looks something like this. Basically, the goal would be to figure out how many entries there are total, utilizing the fact that the first integer gives an idea of how many total lines follow for the rest of the entry.

Comment: Are the 'fixed' lines in any way distinguishable from the 'variable' lines? If not, it's not going to be possible to determine `n` before you've exhausted the file.. It might still be possible to optimise by using some clever data structure.

Comment: Hi, yes they are. The fixed lines are various floating point integers, while the "variable" line is an integer. Have edited my post to make that clear.

Comment: Would you mind adding a full sample input file (for some small value of `n`, and small number of entries) and roughly what your code should do? That would be helpful to better understand your requirements.

Comment: I added two example sample input files and explained the general gist of this. Does this make sense?

Comment: Read an integer `n`, then skip `2 * n + 5` lines using `next`, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this code to work with your given example. It doesn't know at the start how many entries there are, but it just keeps reading from the file until the file is exhausted, in order to pull each entry. I've saved your sample input in `input.txt`. I've now also modified the code to read the data in as floats.

```
import pprint
import functools

#helper function for reading multiple lines
def read_n(in_file, n):
    return [in_file.readline() for _ in range(n)]

#read one line of floats
def read_floats(line):
    return list(map(float, line.split()))

#reads several lines of floats
def float_lines(lines):
    return [read_floats(line) for line in lines]

def parse_entry(in_file):
    #get n
    n = in_file.readline().strip()

    if n:
        n = int(n)

        #read 3, n, 1, n, 1 lines
        head = float_lines(read_n(in_file, 3))
        head_data = [(line[0], read_floats(line[1:])) for line in map(str.strip, read_n(in_file, n))]
        mid = float(in_file.readline().strip())
        tail_data = float_lines(read_n(in_file, n))
        tail = float(in_file.readline().strip())

        #readline to eat the empty line between entries
        in_file.readline()

        return n, head, head_data, mid, tail_data, tail

with open("input.txt", "r") as input_file:
    #apply parse_entry until it stops returning
    entries = list(iter(functools.partial(parse_entry, input_file), None))

print(len(entries))
pprint.pprint(entries)
```

Which outputs:

```
2
[(5,
  [[10.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 10.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 10.0]],
  [('A', [-0.005364798, -0.022912843, 0.017346957]),
   ('B', [0.527031905, 0.60331015, 0.560736787]),
   ('B', [-0.62946685, -0.628385741, 0.628048126]),
   ('B', [-0.649090857, 0.603667874, -0.72613588]),
   ('B', [0.683741908, -0.584386774, -0.700569743])],
  -17.862057,
  [[-2.022841336, -1.477407454, -5.606136767],
   [2.521789668, 2.88925177, 2.572440406],
   [-0.401914888, -0.722582908, 0.244151982],
   [0.806040926, -0.990697574, 1.474733506],
   [-0.903074369, 0.301436166, 1.314862295]],
  0.016462),
 (7,
  [[10.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 10.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 10.0]],
  [('A', [-0.591644968, -0.645755982, -0.014245979]),
   ('B', [1.198655655, -0.58887208, -0.025169784]),
   ('B', [-1.46077458, -1.255848596, 0.025804796]),
   ('B', [0.321839745, 2.199107994, 0.050450166]),
   ('C', [0.61768472, -1.389588077, -0.075897238]),
   ('C', [0.493712792, 1.349385956, -0.004249822]),
   ('D', [-0.808145644, 0.577304796, 0.014326943])],
  -26.435922,
  [[1.649465696, -2.945456091, -0.152209323],
   [0.531241391, -1.113956273, -0.135548573],
   [-0.529287352, -0.556746737, -0.061346528],
   [-2.152476371, 6.326868481, 0.441458459],
   [-1.633473432, 3.325310912, 0.291306019],
   [0.726490986, -8.268565793, -0.51257518],
   [1.408090505, 3.232545501, 0.128915126]],
  0.155658)]
```

Demonstrating that it's found 2 entries, and has parsed them as floats, and then outputs the entries. I'm not entirely sure what the entries are, so I've kept them ambiguously named. Note that I've preserved as much data as I can of the entries in my big list-tuple structure, because I'm not sure which bits are relevant either, so the original file should almost be reconstructable from the entries in memory.

Regarding the lines starting with a character - this is approached by first applying `str.strip` to the line, as sometimes there is a space before the character. It then separates the `line` into `line[0]` and `line[1:]`, which is the character, and a slice of the string representing the data, which is then operated on as normal.

More on how I separate the characters from the floats:

Take the following line:

```
 A       -0.005364798      -0.022912843       0.017346957
```

This will be parsed by:

```
head_data = [(line[0], read_floats(line[1:])) for line in map(str.strip, read_n(in_file, n))]
```

However, if we're considering only this line, we can look at less of the expression. The first thing that happens to the line is `str.strip`, from `map(str.strip..)`. This strips any trailing and leading whitespace to ensure the first character is the letter to be removed. This means the state of the line in memory is now:

```
"A       -0.005364798      -0.022912843       0.017346957"
```

The line is then separated into `line[0]` and `read_floats(line[1:])`. This is where the distinction between the string and floats is made - the string is separated away from the rest of the string, which is then passed to `read_floats`. This is using slice notation, a powerful syntax Python has for getting sublists of iterables. The slice `1:` means 'slice from index 1 to the end of the string'. For clarity:

```
line[0] == "A"
line[1:] == "      -0.005364798      -0.022912843       0.017346957"
```

`for _` is a Python convention for when you just need to repeat something, without keeping track of which repetition it is.  ie it reads a line for each number in the `range(n)`, so it reads `n` lines, but it doesn't need to keep track of which number the current line is. It could just as well say `for i in range(n)`, except `i` would be unused, so the iterator is called `_` to indicate you don't want it.

`if n:` checks if the string `n` is not empty. This is because when you `readline()` a file that has been exhausted, an empty string is returned. This means instead of crashing when it's done with the file, the program will just neatly stop parsing entries. This is important as we don't know the number of entries, so we keep trying to read an `n` until we can no longer read an `n`, so we have to use an if statement.

Regarding why entries looks so convoluted - `parse_entry(input_file)` would only parse a single entry. All of the other baggage is required to parse all entries. `functools.partial(parse_entry, input_file)` means 'apply the argument `input_file` to the function `parse_entry`'. This then uses `iter` to keep doing this until it returns `None`. This is quite a useful trick - the iter function can be given any function and then a value to stop at, and it will keep returning values from the function until it hits the 'stop' value. A simpler, more often seen example might be `iter(sys.stdin.readline, "a\n")`. This would keep reading lines from `stdin` until it hit a line containing only `a`.

On tuples and tuple unpacking - you could do this:

```
for n, head, head_data, mid, tail_data, tail in entries:
    print("n is {}".format(n))
    print("the first item of head_data is {}".format(head_data[0]))

    for i in tail_data:
        print("tail data item: {}".format(i))
```

This results in the output:

```
n is 5
the first item of head_data is ('A', [-0.005364798, -0.022912843, 0.017346957])
tail data item: [-2.022841336, -1.477407454, -5.606136767]
tail data item: [2.521789668, 2.88925177, 2.572440406]
tail data item: [-0.401914888, -0.722582908, 0.244151982]
tail data item: [0.806040926, -0.990697574, 1.474733506]
tail data item: [-0.903074369, 0.301436166, 1.314862295]
n is 7
the first item of head_data is ('A', [-0.591644968, -0.645755982, -0.014245979])
tail data item: [1.649465696, -2.945456091, -0.152209323]
tail data item: [0.531241391, -1.113956273, -0.135548573]
tail data item: [-0.529287352, -0.556746737, -0.061346528]
tail data item: [-2.152476371, 6.326868481, 0.441458459]
tail data item: [-1.633473432, 3.325310912, 0.291306019]
tail data item: [0.726490986, -8.268565793, -0.51257518]
tail data item: [1.408090505, 3.232545501, 0.128915126]
```

Hopefully this demonstrates how you might go about making use of the structure.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for having a go at this! When I tried running this on my big data set of entries (input.txt), I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.0 0.0 0.0' This was similar to the error I was getting when I tried this with my own code. It seems like int() is checking this second line and not the first line? 

Keeping the next lines as strings seems like it should be fine, the important thing is just making sure the first line is read as an integer.

Comment: Okay I've *almost* gone to bed. I suspect that this is because your dataset either doesn't have blank lines in between entries or inconsistently has them. If it doesn't have them, you can remove the empty-line-eater. If it sometimes has them, I really will have to do this in the morning.

Comment: Oh you know I think I figured out that part, thanks for your help! I was wondering if you could help out with one last thing which was about reading in a line of floats, like you said. If I wanted to read in certain lines as floats (i.e. 10.0 0.0 0.0) but then I also wanted to read in a line like "A -0.005364798      -0.022912843       0.017346957" which would be a character followed by floats, do you know the python best practice way of doing that?

Comment: The code is now modified to work with floats. Let me know if it should be changed and I'll do so after work. Note I've left it using my line-eater as I'm unclear what the problem was.

Comment: Thank you so much! For the "head_data" part, what is the specific command you used to specify that the first value was a string and the rest were a float? I saw you did line[0] to call the first entry, when you did "for line in map(str.strip, read_n(in_file, n))", how did you only map the first entry to a string? (Also I have accepted your answer but just asked this from a learning perspective)

Comment: I've added some more on how the separation works. Let me know if you'd like any more clarification, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152950/discussion-between-j-p-and-izaak-van-dongen).